# PHP md5 generating different hash each time

Tags: php, function, md5

I have a form which is storing an `md5`'ed password.

For testing purposes I am using "**12345**" as a password.

To save the password I use: `$password = md5($password);`

Using the same code and the same password the PHP is creating a different `md5` hash everytime although I'm using the same password each time.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible with `md5()` , The hash will **never** change for a given text , It's definitely wrong with your implementation.

#### The two cases of failure

- Maybe you are passing the `md5()` hashed password as an argument to the `md5()` function again and again.
- There maybe some whitespace getting added to your `$password`. Just `trim()` it  as shown below.

  `$password = md5(trim($password));`

  **Remember** : Even a space can change your hash.